# MTR returning strange results. Multiple results per hop

Tags: linux, networking

I'm troubleshooting some voip issues and discovered this result using MTR.  It's very strange and confuses me.  Can anyone shed some light on what might be happening?  I'm seeing 2 IP's for each hop after hop 1.  However the second IP of each HOP is the final destination's IP.

```
 Host                                                                                                          Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
 1. 172.17.115.1                                                                                                0.0%    40    0.2   0.6   0.2   3.7   0.8
 2. 97-64-171-1.client.mchsi.com                                                                                0.0%    40    3.2   3.3   3.0   4.6   0.2
    67.231.1.170
 3. 68-66-73-149.client.mchsi.com                                                                               0.0%    40    2.9   3.4   2.8  20.2   2.7
    67.231.1.170
 4. 68-66-72-61.client.mchsi.com                                                                                0.0%    40   14.8  15.4  14.6  38.1   3.6
    67.231.1.170
 5. 68-66-73-105.client.mchsi.com                                                                               0.0%    40   15.0  14.9  14.6  15.7   0.0
    67.231.1.170
 6. stlo-b1-link.telia.net                                                                                      0.0%    40   14.6  15.3  14.5  35.5   3.3
    67.231.1.170
 7. kanc-b1-link.telia.net                                                                                      0.0%    40   20.3  20.5  20.0  27.0   1.5
    67.231.1.170
 8. dls-b22-link.telia.net                                                                                      0.0%    40   35.6  31.5  30.5  52.2   3.7
    67.231.1.170
 9. bandwidth-ic-319125-dls-b22.c.telia.net                                                                     0.0%    40   30.6  33.1  30.5  41.9   3.8
    67.231.1.170
10. ip-241.dfw1.bandwidthclec.com                                                                               0.0%    40   30.6  33.2  30.5  58.5   5.4
    67.231.1.170
11. 67.231.1.234                                                                                                0.0%    39   30.7  32.5  30.5  42.6   3.5
    67.231.1.170
12. 67.231.1.170                                                                                               68.4%    39   31.0  31.0  30.9  31.1   0.0
    67.231.1.212
```

Comment: This reply is from the author of MTR

Answer (score 0):

This according to the author of MTR

MTR is just a tool. It displays the info it gets. Its not going to
"make up" things.

MTR sends out packets with an uncommonly low TTL, as if the packet has
been in the network already for 63, 62, 61... hops.  That would mean
that the TTL, time to live, is set at 1, 2, 3... when it leaves the
host running MTR. So after 1, 2, 3... hops the router there gets a
packet with a TTL of zero and MUST send back an error message.

So what we observe is that packets that go out with a time-to-live of
2 somehow still end up at the destination.

My theory is that 97-64-171-1.client.mchsi.com instead of "reporting
error" will auto-correct the TTL and pass it on towards the
destination with the TTL set to something normal again. And apparently
it also does this for packets that are just "passing through".

This could be a "nasty bug" that nobody noticed, because under normal
circumstances, nobody will notice this.
Or it could be that the programmers of that router encoutered some
problem and used this trick to try and circumvent that problem.

Comment: "_the router there gets a packet with a TTL of zero and MUST send back an error message._" Many routers are configured to not send an ICMP message on TTL expiration. Also, its if a router receives a packet with a TTL of `1` when it sends the ICMP message. That is because it will decrement the TTL, and it cannot then forward the packet.

Comment: Ron, if many routers are configured to not send an ICMP message on TTL expiration, do they send nothing?  Or something else?

Comment: They do nothing, traceroute gets dots. Also, MPLS may skip because it is using routers as layer-2 devices. You often see nothing but dots for a while when crossing an MPLS cloud. Also, ISPs often want to disguise their network design, so they may reroute such traffic (ICMP and/or low TTL values) so that your traceroute traffic show a different path than your real traffic takes. These types of tools are useful on your network where you know what to expect, but can be misleading or useless on the public Internet.